# How to apply zoom transition on label and textbox simultaneously in HTML/CSS?

Tags: css, html

I tried form in HTML and I want to hover zoom transition on label and text box at same time, like if I put a cursor on label then label and text box both zoomed. I tried many codes and YouTube. I can hover both separately but I don't know how to zoom at same time.can anyone have any coding idea.

*this is html code : and above is css code plz check both codes because i want to hover simultaneously if i active cursor on label then both label and text area will be zoomed*
i tried many option but i failed to get answer .if anyone helps me because its my college assignment and i am stuck with it badly please i want it fast answer

```css
label {
  transform: 56px;
  font-width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  text-align: top;
}
label:hover {
  font-size: 40px;
}
input:hover {
  font-size: 40px;
}
#preview {
  margin-top: 8.5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 20%;
}
fieldset {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 600px height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>PLEASE ENTER YOUR DETAIL FOR OUR DATING SITE</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>YOUR FACE</legend>
    <label>YOUR IMAGE</label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" required>
    <br>
    <label>image preview:</label>
    <img id="preview">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>YOUR GENERAL DETAIL</legend>
    <label>NAME</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Gender</label>
    : Male
    <input type="radio" width="180px">Female
    <input type="radio">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="number" width="180px">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Date of birth:</label>
    <input type="date" width="180px">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Favourite color:</label>
    <input type="color" width="180px">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Which country:</label>
    <select required width="180px">
      <br>
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option>America</option>
      <option>Pakistan</option>
      <option>Egypt</option>
      <option>Turkey</option>
      <option>China</option>
      <option>Japan</option>
      <br>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your indicators</legend>
    <br>
    <label>Height:</label>
    Short
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" ;>Tall
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Salary:Poor</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100">Rich
    <br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Contact Information</legend>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" style="width:180;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Mobile:</label>
    <input type="tel " width="180px ">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Method to contact you:</label>
    <input type="checkbox " ; width="auto ">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="checkbox ">
    <label>Whatsapp</label>
    <input type="checkbox ">
    <label>In-appchat</label>
    <input type="checkbox ">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit " value="Submit ">



  <script src="https://www.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/dating_web_site.js "></script>
</form>
```

Comment: How about using javascript?

Comment: Please add your HTML, BTW it's a good idea to create a code snippet in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)** to choose the `input` next to the hovered `label`.

```css
label {
  transform: 56px;
  font-width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  text-align: top;
}
label:hover, label:hover + input, label:hover + select, label:hover + textarea {
  font-size: 40px;
}
#preview {
  margin-top: 8.5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 20%;
}
fieldset {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 600px height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>PLEASE ENTER YOUR DETAIL FOR OUR DATING SITE</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>YOUR FACE</legend>
    <label>YOUR IMAGE</label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" required>
    <br>
    <label>image preview:</label>
    <img id="preview">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>YOUR GENERAL DETAIL</legend>
    <label>NAME</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Gender</label>
    : Male
    <input type="radio" width="180px">Female
    <input type="radio">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="number" width="180px">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Date of birth:</label>
    <input type="date" width="180px">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Favourite color:</label>
    <input type="color" width="180px">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Which country:</label>
    <select required width="180px">
      <br>
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option>America</option>
      <option>Pakistan</option>
      <option>Egypt</option>
      <option>Turkey</option>
      <option>China</option>
      <option>Japan</option>
      <br>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your indicators</legend>
    <br>
    <label>Height:</label>
    Short
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" ;>Tall
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Salary:Poor</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100">Rich
    <br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Contact Information</legend>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" style="width:180;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Mobile:</label>
    <input type="tel " width="180px ">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Method to contact you:</label>
    <input type="checkbox " ; width="auto ">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="checkbox ">
    <label>Whatsapp</label>
    <input type="checkbox ">
    <label>In-appchat</label>
    <input type="checkbox ">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit " value="Submit ">



  <script src="https://www.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/dating_web_site.js "></script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap the `<label>` around the `<input>`.

```
<label>TEXT
  <input>
</label>
```

#### SNIPPET

```css
label {
  transform: 56px;
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  text-align: top;
}
label:hover, label:focus {
  font-size: 40px;
}

input:hover, label:focus {
  font-size: 40px;
}
#preview {
  margin-top: 8.5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 20%;
}
fieldset {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 600px height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>PLEASE ENTER YOUR DETAIL FOR OUR DATING SITE</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>YOUR FACE</legend>
    <label>YOUR IMAGE
      <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" required>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>image preview:</label>
    <img id="preview">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>YOUR GENERAL DETAIL</legend>
    <label>NAME
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Gender : Male
      <input type="radio">
    </label>
    <label>
      Female
      <input type="radio">
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Age:
      <input type="number" width="180px">
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Date of birth:
      <input type="date" width="180px">
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Favourite color:
      <input type="color" width="180px">
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Which country:
    <select required width="180px">
      <br>
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option>America</option>
      <option>Pakistan</option>
      <option>Egypt</option>
      <option>Turkey</option>
      <option>China</option>
      <option>Japan</option>
      <br>
    </select>
      </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your indicators</legend>
    <br>
    <label>Height:
    Short
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" ;>Tall</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Salary:Poor
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100">Rich</label>
    <br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Contact Information</legend>
    <label>Email:
      <input type="email" style="width:180;">
    </label>
    <br>

    <br>
    <label>Mobile:
      <input type="tel " width="180px ">
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Method to contact you:
      <input type="checkbox " width="auto">
    </label>
    <label>Email
      <input type="checkbox ">
    </label>

    <label>Whatsapp
      <input type="checkbox ">
    </label>
    <label>In-appchat
      <input type="checkbox ">
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit " value="Submit ">



  <script src="https://www.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/dating_web_site.js "></script>
</form>
```